# text with input in one row

Tags: html, css

I have div with input field and text

Here is code

```css
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #1f66b4;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    background-image: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:50%;height:100%;float: left;padding-left:20%">
            <form style="text-align:center;">
                <b>dfsdfsdfsdf</b>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" style="margin: 30px auto 0;border-radius:50px;border-width: 1px;">
            </form>
        </div>
```

But text is over input.

[image]

I need to make text in one row with input.
How I can do this?

Comment: Flexbox, floats, tables, absolute positioning...

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RgBxqq Seems fine here. I think we need to know more about where you're doing this.

Comment: You code already works: https://jsfiddle.net/5kmLszv6/ Do you have more information about your problem?

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: probably the width of the container is not wide enough to hold both in a single line, try increasing the width of the parent container. Could you update it with some more code work, so that we could help?

Comment: I edited post@JefreeSujit

Answer (score 0):

Hope what you already have works fine. Check it out by running the snippet below.

```html
<div style="width:50%;height:100%;float: left;padding-left:20%">
        <form style="text-align:center;">
            <b>dfsdfsdfsdf</b>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" style="margin: 30px auto 0;border-radius:50px;border-width: 1px;">
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the input tag inside a **div**.
Use **label** tag instead of b tag  (it helps screen readers)
then give css "**float:left**" for the label and div(wrapping the input)

atlast remove the margin from your input and giv some margin-top for the label
and after float, **clear** it

```
<div style="width:50%;height:100%;float: left;padding-left:20%">
    <form style="text-align:center;">
        <label style="float:left; margin-top:6px">dfsdfsdfsdf</label>
        <div style="float:left">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" style="border-radius:50px;border-width: 1px;">
        </div>
        <div style="clear:left">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: label is showing in top left corner ща page, and not in div.

Answer (score 0):

You can add padding for the placeholder but browser support requires prefixes.

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  padding-left: .3em;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  padding-left: .3em;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  padding-left: .3em;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  padding-left: .3em;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:50%;height:100%;float: left;padding-left:20%">
  <form style="text-align:center;">
    <b>dfsdfsdfsdf</b>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" style="margin: 30px auto 0;border-radius:50px;border-width: 1px;">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <div style="width:50%;height:100%;float: left;padding-left:20%">
            <form style="text-align:center;">
                <lable> dfsdfsdfsdf</label> 
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" style="margin: 30px auto 0;border-radius:50px;border-width: 1px;">
            </form>
        </div>
```